# How can I access smb shares in Nautilus while connected to a VPN?

Tags: mount, nautilus, samba, vpn

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 (I think). I'm having a spot of difficulty connecting to local SMB shares while also connected to a VPN.

If I click on the share bookmark in Nautilus (down the left side panel), it just spins endlessly. The same result is achieved if I right-click on the share and say, "Open in new tab". ("Open in new window" doesn't seem to do anything.)

If I disconnect from the VPN, it will mount right away. Needless to say, disconnecting from the VPN whenever I want to access the shared drive is not my desired solution. Nor, I think, should I have to do this if my system is correctly configured.

I have added an explicit entry for the smb server in the routing table (`route add`, etc.) so that my computer knows to send traffic to the smb server over the local network and not the VPN.

While connected to the VPN, I can mount the share using smbclient, so it's not a problem with network access.

I have forced nautilus to quit while the routing table is set up and the VPN is enabled, using `nautilus -q` on the command line, in the hope that this would make nautilus reload the routing table when next started, in case nautilus had an older version of the routing table stored in some kind of internal cache.

I have also tried loading the share directly with gvfs-mount from the command line and it just hangs with no text output until the VPN is disabled. I can't see an option to run gvfs-mount in any kind of verbose or debug mode, and I have no idea where if anywhere it is logging to.

The unhelpful behaviour would seem to come from gvfs-mount therefore. Has anyone seen this and is there a solution (to allow gvfs-mount to work using the routing table while connected to the VPN)?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried pressing ctrl-l to get an address box at the top of Nautilus, then typing `smb://ip-address-of-vpn-server/share-name` ?